# Convert output number format with a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running this query through a unix command line:

```
SELECT X FROM TABLEX WHERE NAME LIKE 'Blablabla';
```

The output result should be 304768764529, however a get as return 3.047E11.

How can I, with a single query, convert the result to be the exact number, not in the scientific mode?

Comment: You have both mysql and oracle tagged.  Which is it?

Comment: `SELECT cast(X as UNSIGNED) FROM TABLEX WHERE NAME LIKE 'Blablabla';`

Comment: @Gerrat While it IS confusing, please remember that MySQL is an Oracle database.

Comment: @EugenRieck The `oracle` tag definition: `Oracle Server is an Object-relational Database Management System (ORDBMS) created by Oracle Corporation. Do NOT use this tag for other products owned by Oracle, such as Java and MySQL.`

Comment: @Gerrat I stand corrected - please disregard my comment. TBH I didn't know there was such a thing as a definition for a tag ... my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using Oracle RDBMS, you can do it this way:

```
SELECT to_char(X)
  FROM TABLEX
 WHERE NAME LIKE 'Blablabla';
```

I'm curious why you're using `LIKE` without wildcards though.